# Constrained integer partition

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, integer-partitions

## Challenge

**In this challenge**, all numbers are in \$\mathbb{N}_0\$.

Create a function or program that, when given a number \$N\$ and a tuple of \$k\$ numbers \$(n_i)\$ (all ≤ \$N\$), returns the number of ways \$N\$ can be written as a sum of \$k\$ integers (\$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k\$) such that \$n_i \le x_i \le N\$.

The input format is not fixed. You can read and parse strings, take two parameters as int and int[], etc.

This is a variation of the classical **Integer Partition** problem.

## Test Cases

\$N=4, n=(0, 0, 2) \implies 6\$ `(2+0+2, 1+1+2, 0+2+2, 1+0+3, 0+1+3, 0+0+4)`

\$N=121, n=(7, 16, 21, 36, 21, 20) \implies 1\$ `(7+16+21+36+21+20)`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest byte count for each language wins!

Comment: Do we have to support the edge case where all \$n_i=0\$?

Comment: I'm sorry if i dont get the question right, but how are you getting 1+0+3 in the first test case, when 3, or 1 are not in the tuple `n`?

Comment: @EliteDaMyth the numbers are not required to be *in* the tuple, but to be elementwise greater than or equal to the numbers in the tuple. Here, (1,0,3) elementwise ≥ (0, 0, 2)

Comment: @Arnauld yes, in that case it reduces to the general partition problem

Comment: This seems like a well-written challenge, but in future, I'd recommend posting in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback first

Comment: Isn't this just the number of ways that \$N - (x_1 + \cdots + x_k)\$ can be written as the sum of \$k\$ non-negative integers?

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
rŒp§ċ
```

A dyadic Link accepting the lower bound tuple on the left and the total on the right which yields the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/o6KSCQ8uPdP///z/aQEcBiIxi/5sAAA)**

#### How?

```
rŒp§ċ - Link: T, N       e.g. [2,1,3], 5
r     - inclusive range       [[2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
 Œp   - Cartesian product     [[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,1,4],[2,1,5],[2,2,1],...,[5,5,4],[5,5,5]]
   §  - sums                  [ 4,      5,      6,      7,      8,      5,     ..., 14,     15]
    ċ - count (Ns)            2
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 35 bytes

```hs
n%(x:t)=sum$map(%t)[0..n-x]
n%_=0^n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcRBCoAgEADAe6/YQwsFW6wWBYEvEQsPQVEukQb93qA5zObjsZ5nzoLVO6XaxCeUwV8Vptpy20rzukJwMTxLDn4XMHDduySwPVomJu0IlFZoR1IDaUXdv2bnIH8)

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)*

```
#¹mΣΠm…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/nQztxzi88tyH3UsOz///8m/6MNdAx0jGIB)

```
#¹         # number of times that arg 1 appears in the list of
  mΣ       # sums of
    Π      # cartesian product of
     m     # mapping
      …    # range up to arg 1
           # for each element of arg 2
```

Comment: Nice answer! You can save a [couple bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/nQztxzi88tyH3UsOz///8m/6MNdAx0jGIB) by messing around with superscripts

Comment: @user - Thanks!  I did try to get rid of the superscripts at the end, but never seemed to find the right permutation...

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.8+, 62 bytes

```python
import math
f=lambda S,N:math.comb(S-sum(N)+len(N)-1,len(N)-1)
```

The result can be found using the formula:

$$R = \binom{N-(\Sigma x_i)+k-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: Shouldn't have trusted the byte counter, I forgot I was on Windows so the CR added 1 byte to the count.

Comment: You can make your function anonymous, and also use the new assignment operator to save a few [bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFYx88qN7EkQy85PzdJI1i3uDRXw09TWyPHyjYnNQ/I1DXU1MnR5MrMLcgvKlEAKf1fUJSZV6KRpmGiE22gY6BjFKupyQUTMzQy1Ik21zE00wEyjMGkkQFQwX8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>62</s> 51 bytes

```ruby
->n,k{[*1..n-k.sum+z=k.size-1].combination(z).size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ7s6WstQTy9PN1uvuDRXu8oWSGdWpeoaxuol5@cmZeYllmTm52lUaYKFa/8XKKRFm@hEG@gY6BjFxnKBuIZGhjrR5jqGZjpAhjGYNDKIjf0PAA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 65 bytes

Expects `(n)(list)`. Uses the [formula provided by the OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219572/58563).

```javascript
n=>a=>(n-=eval(a.join`-1+`),g=k=>!k||g(--k)*(k-n)/~k)(a.length-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcqxDsIgEIDh3bdwu1OuApo6wYsYk5JKsYUcxjadGl8diZvLv3z/5FY39@/xtRDnhy@DKWysMxaYjF9dAtdMeeSO1LFDEUw0dh@3LQBRxANEYjx9ItYteQ7LkxSWPvOck29SDjDABeEmhRT6jrj7J6VVxatQrdBKnH/Vsn7lCw)

#### How?

The expression `eval(a.join('-1+'))` subtracts 1 from all entries in `a[]` except the last one and sums everything. For instance:

```
[ 2, 3, 4 ] --> "2-1+3-1+4" --> 7
```

So, this is equivalent to: $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i-k+1$$

We could also use `eval(a.join('+~-'))` which subtracts 1 from all entries but the first one, leading to the same result.

The helper function `g` computes the combination.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 46 bytes

**(using n_choose_k)**

```r
function(x,y)choose(x-sum(y)+(z=sum(y|1)-1),z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfV5qblFoUn58WX55YWWz7P600L7kkMz9Po0KnUjM5Iz@/OFWjQre4NFejUlNbo8oWzKox1NQ11NSp0kTTrmGik6xhoGOgY6Sp@R8A)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 58 bytes

**(by enumeration)**

```r
function(x,y)sum(rowSums(z<-expand.grid(Map(`:`,y,x)))==x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcy7DYAgEADQde6S0xhjZWQEKwcQBDEUfAISweWx9w3wYnPZHmfcvd4fURNrOjt5G@@gUMWULUT/bNkmeJfuLEE41V/RKFhFAD5zqlQQkbGCvwomkjDQQCNi@wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

port of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219567/98541)

```julia
n>N=n==[]?0^N:sum([n[2:end]].>0:N-n[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/z87PNs/WNjrW3iDOz6q4NFcjOi/ayCo1LyU2Vs/OwMpPNy86VvN/QVFmXklOnka0gY6BjlGsnYkmF1zIXMfQTMfIUMcYTBoZxNoZGhlq/gcA)

#### alternative answer, 38 bytes too

```julia
!N=0^N;!(N,x,t...)=sum(.!(0:N-x,t...))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9f0c/WIM7PWlHDT6dCp0RPT0/Ttrg0V0NPUcPAyk8XKqT5P8/OzxakJg/E5SooyswrycnTiDbQMdAxirUzQRIy1zE00zEy1DEGk0YGsXaGRoaa/wE)

a few more bytes with julia 1.0+

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
.c+-hAQsHJtlHJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy9ZWzfDMbDYw6skx8Pr/38TnWgDHQMdo1gA)

Translation of [zdimension](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25314/zdimension)['s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219564/constrained-integer-partition/219572#219572).

## 14 bytes

```
/sMsM*F}RGeAQG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X7/Yt9hXy602yD3VMdD9/38TnWgDHQMdo1gA)

Translation of [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)['s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219564/constrained-integer-partition/219566#219566).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES2020), 59 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,[h,...t],s=0)=>eval('for(;n>=h;)s+=f(n-h++,t)')??!n&!h
```

```js
f=(n,[h,...t],s=0)=>eval('for(;n>=h;)s+=f(n-h++,t)')??!n&!h

console.log(f(4, [0,0,2]));
console.log(f(121, [7,16,21,36,21,20]));
```

Firefox 72+, Chrome 80+, IE no. TIO currently out of date.

Simple brute force, literally.

- `eval()` return *completion value* of given statement(s).

  - Completion value of `for` statement is completion value of its execute body in last iteration.
  - Completion value of assignment is the value assigned.
  - In case the control flow does not goes into for loop due to the looping condition, `for` statement has no completion value.
  - As the result, `eval(for(;n>=h;)...)` returns the value of `s` (an integer) if once `n>=h`, and return `undefined` if `n>=h` never happened.
- `??` is nullish coalescing operator which is introduced in ES2020.

  - If left side of `??` is null or undefined, it equals to right side. Otherwise, it returns left side (short circuit evaluation). (Similar as what `??` in C# do.)
  - If `n>=h` is falsy, it may due to `n<h` or `h` is undefined.
  - We found a valid integer partition as long as `n == 0` and `h` is undefined (undefined value of `h` means the array is empty.).
  - `!n&!h` check both `n` and `h` are falsy. As `n` may only be integers, it would be `0`. `h` may be integers or undefined. But if `h === 0`, `n >= h` is true, the `??` operator short circuit current expression. As the result, we know `h` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
≔…¹ＬηζＩ÷Π⁺ζ⁻θΣηΠζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYu7CgIxEAB7vyLlBlY4xe4q0UZQCFoeV4RcSAJxD/O4Ij@/msJuBmaM18msOjKfcw6O4KnJWTiguFtyxYOXEkWT406lQAUuOhe4UbmGLSwWVFqXagqoWDM0FI9AP/igeNV3X/v8b1rXkXk64TTggMd55v0Wvw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Based on the OP's formula.

```
≔…¹Ｌηζ
```

Get the exclusive range from `1` to `k`.

```
Ｉ÷Π⁺ζ⁻θΣηΠζ
```

Subtract the sum of `xᵢ` from `N`, add it element-wise to the the range, take the product, and divide by the product of the range. This is equivalent to calculating the number of combinations.